# AWS Lambda http, where do I find the URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am fairly new to `AWS Lambda` but sure can see the benefits of it and stumbled upon the superb framework `Serverless` to help me built solutions on Lambda.

I started out building solutions using `AWS API` Gateway but really need `"internal" VPC API`'s and not public Internet facing API's like API GW creates.

I found that `Servless` indeed can expose a `HTTP` endpoint but I can't figure out how this is done and how the URL is created.
When I deploy the Lambda from Serverless it gives me the URL, e.g.:

https://uxezd6ry8z.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ping

I would like to be able to find (or create) this same http listener for already existing `Lambdas` so my question is how is the `URL` created and where is teh actual `HTTP` listener deployed?

Comment: You don't create the url yourself. You create the HTTP methods, aws gives you the urls for those methods. You just bind the methods with a lambda_handler function.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-invoke-manually.html

Comment: API Gateway endpoints are always public Internet facing. The API Gateway service does not provide private VPC endpoints.

Comment: I know API GW creates public endpoints, that's what I want to avoid having!

Comment: @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi, you write "aws gives you the urls for those methods". That is exactly my question, where do I find that URL in the Lambda console?

Comment: The URL you mentioned, in the format `{identifier}.execute-api.{aws-region}.amazonaws.com` is, in fact, an API gateway URL.  So, this is clearly not what you are looking for.

Comment: You can execute your lambdas (send events) using AWS SDK. May I ask what type of work do you want the lambda to do?

Comment: If you don't want to use an API Gateway, as the question specifies, you can assign a "Function URL" in the AWS Console. Go to the Lambda dashboard and select your Lambda function. Select the **Configuration** tab. Select **Function URL** in the left nav. Here you can create an authenticated or unauthenticated (public) URL that will receive POSTs from `curl` and pass them on to your Lambda function.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Duh, I was in the wrong AWS logon previously so the API GW was not showing any matching Serverless API and that was why I couldn't understand how they did it...

Once I logged into the AWS account that hosts the Serverless structure I can see the API GW GET API's for the Serverless HTTP listener.

Comment: This is not the answer, the previous post is.

Comment: In my case it is, I knew where to look for it but I was logged into another AWS account which didn't have the same setup...

Comment: Not an answer anyway,

Comment: Even the popular answer about how to find API Gateway URLs is not a good answer either because the question mentions internal URLs, specifically *not* API Gateway URLs.

Answer (score 50):

You might be looking for the invoke url,
1. go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway
2. select **api link** (which you have deployed on aws lambda).
[image]
3. select **stages** in left side panel and
see the **invoke url**.
[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks, this was what I was looking for but as I was in the wrong AWS account the one from Serverless and in the Console didn't match having me confused and I thought Serverless somehow created their own URL... hence my confusion... :)

Comment: Thank u this is what i need

Answer (score 29):

Adding a http listener can be done by going to your lambda function, selecting the 'triggers' tab and 'add trigger', finally selecting API Gateway - but as others mentioned this does create a public facing url.

[image: adding api gateway as a trigger will give you a url to an existing lambda]

Comment: On the Configuration tab a "Function URL" can be created that works without an API Gateway. These can be authenticated or unauthenticated but I believe they are still public.